# Dojo script loading error

Tags: javascript, dojo

We are doing a project with Dojox and have been struggling to load the cript. We tried using the Google cdn link: .

We also tried to import the toolkit into our project. But, failed. Gives an "Uncaught Reference error". Any help appreciated. 
Below is my code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="dojo-release-1.9.1/dojox/charting"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  require(['dojox/charting/Chart2D','dojox/charting/axis2d/Default','dojox/charting/plot2d/De    fault','dojox/charting/plot2d/Spider','dojox/charting/axis2d/Base'],function(Chart,     Default, Default, Spider, Base){
     var chart = new dojox.charting.Chart("test");
     chart.addPlot("default", {
     type:         "Spider",
     labelOffset:      -10,
     seriesFillAlpha:     0.2,
     markerSize:       3,
     precision:         0,
     spiderType:          "polygon"
 }); 


var data= [ {"CPU Utilization":1,"NetworkIn":444,"DiskReadBytes":1.00002,"NetworkOut":360.00001,"DiskWriteBytes":1.00002},
{"CPU Utilization":1.0001,"NetworkIn":444,"DiskReadBytes":1.0002,"NetworkOut":360.00001,"DiskWriteBytes":1},
{"CPU Utilization":1,"NetworkIn":486.00002,"DiskReadBytes":1.00001,"NetworkOut":360.00001,"DiskWriteBytes":1} ];


chart.addSeries("min", {data: data[0] }, { fill: "blue" });
chart.addSeries("max", {data: data[1] }, { fill: "blue" });
chart.addSeries("USA", {data: data[2] }, { fill: "blue" });

chart.render();
chart.removeSeries("min");
chart.removeSeries("max");
});
</script>
</head>
<body><div id="test" style="width: 400px; height: 240px; margin: 30px auto 0px auto;">       </div></body>
</html>
```

Comment: It looks like the Google CDN link didn't make it into your post. What is the full error that you get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<script src="dojo-release-1.9.1/dojox/charting"></script>
```

Are you sure the above actually works? I think you need to include all of Dojo. The Google CDN link would be `//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.9.1/dojo/dojo.js`; try that and see if it helps.

---

The `require` callback is what takes the arguments of the modules in your dependency list, not the `dojo.ready` call. **You also can't duplicate arguments in the callback list**, like you did with `Default`. So, your `require` call should look something like the following.

```
require([
    'dojox/charting/Chart2D',
    'dojox/charting/axis2d/Default',
    'dojox/charting/plot2d/Default',
    'dojox/charting/plot2d/Spider',
    'dojox/charting/axis2d/Base'
], function(Chart, DefaultAxis, DefaultPlot, Spider, Base) {
```

And your `dojo.ready` call shouldn't take any arguments. You can also include `dojo/ready` as a dependency like all your others, or use the [dojo/domReady!](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dojo/domReady.html) plugin. Any way you do it, it doesn't take your dependencies as arguments, otherwise they'll be overwritten. It should look similar to the following.

```
dojo.ready(function () {
```

---

Other than the above problems with `require` and the `script` tag, the code looks like it works. [Here's a fiddle of the working code with Dojo 1.9 and the dojo/domReady! plugin to make it a little cleaner](http://jsfiddle.net/tupton/9u2pg/). Note the inclusion of a div with id `test`. I wasn't sure if you just didn't paste the rest of that file in your question or if it was actually missing. There are a bunch of errors from the SVG renderer in the console, but the chart works.

Comment: Sorry, pasted the wrong snippet. We didnt have the dojo.ready(). Edited the code snippet.

Comment: Yes, I had missed some Html tags. Now, made it right. Apologies! It works on fiddle. But, still doesnt work on my system. I tried including the given cdn link. It says "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)" and "Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined"

Comment: That error means Dojo isn't loading. If you're trying to load Dojo locally, is `dojo-release-1.9.1/dojox/charting` the correct location? It would seem it is not, at least according to that error. I also updated the Google CDN link in my post.

Comment: Thanks, the error was indeed the cdn link. Tis works perfect. Thanks a lot!